# How to configure NetworkManager to not set default search domain in RHEL8 based distros?

Tags: linux-networking, networkmanager, resolv.conf, rhel8

Assume having a host with single, IPv4 only connection, named ens192, which has statically configured network settings (IP, DNS, gateway), named `vm1.example.invalid`. NetworkManager will add the following string to /etc/resolv.conf:

```
search example.invalid
```

Sometimes you don't want that or want to replace search domain with some other domain. When you do

```
nmcli connection modify ens192 ipv4.dns-search foo.invalid
```

/etc/resolv.conf will contain

```
search foo.invalid example.invalid
```

**The question is:**

How can i unset default `search example.invalid` in generated /etc/resolv.conf, using NetworkManager only?

**What i tried:**

1. Explicitly setting `ipv4.dns-search`, like in example above, setting ipv6.dns-search failed with `this property is not allowed for 'method=ignore'`. Default domain `search` still appended to new dns-search.
2. Reconfiguring server using nm-tui
3. Setting search domain to `.` which is not only useless due to p.1, but also ignored in [source code](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/blob/7cfa8a01cd85ebfa0ebcb4645fa53e03d1aa9be9/src/core/nm-l3-config-data.c#L1395)
4. removing offending domain from /etc/resolv.conf. After restarting NetworkManager - it regenerates back
5. Tried messing with network-scripts - but unsuccessfully

**Workaround:**

In my case, due to existing *.example.invalid wildcard A DNS record, this default search domain setting messed with resolving of non-existing domains and with kubernetes nodes, which are using `ndots 5` by default (relevant [issue for openshift](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/17316) and [an article](https://fabricat.medium.com/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-with-dns-wildcard-entries-and-kubernetes-413df9168ad8)), resulting in broken dns within cluster. I resorted to manual management of /etc/resolv.conf, which is covered by [Redhat docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/manually-configuring-the-etc-resolv-conf-file_configuring-and-managing-networking#replacing-etc-resolv-conf-with-a-symbolic-link-to-manually-configure-dns-settings_manually-configuring-the-etc-resolv-conf-file), and while it works - I'd like to manage networking from one obvious place (NetworkManager), and to understand, why exactly this default record is even added? I tried skimming through NM source code, but not being a C programmer - haven't found a part where this default domain is being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find code here, this behavior is expected

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/blob/main/src/core/dns/nm-dns-manager.c

```
void
nm_dns_manager_set_hostname(NMDnsManager *self, const char *hostname, gboolean skip_update)
{
    NMDnsManagerPrivate *priv   = NM_DNS_MANAGER_GET_PRIVATE(self);
    const char          *domain = NULL;

    /* Certain hostnames we don't want to include in resolv.conf 'searches' */
    if (hostname && nm_utils_is_specific_hostname(hostname)
        && !NM_STR_HAS_SUFFIX(hostname, ".in-addr.arpa")
        && !nm_inet_is_valid(AF_UNSPEC, hostname)) {
        domain = strchr(hostname, '.');
        if (domain) {
            domain++;
            /* If the hostname is a FQDN ("dcbw.example.com"), then add
             * the domain part of it ("example.com") to the searches list,
             * to ensure that we can still resolve its non-FQ form
             * ("dcbw") too. (Also, if there are no other search domains
             * specified, this makes a good default.) However, if the
             * hostname is the top level of a domain (eg, "example.com"),
             * then use the hostname itself as the search (since the user
             * is unlikely to want "com" as a search domain).
             *
             * Because that logic only applies to public domains, the
             * "assume_any_tld_is_public" parameter is FALSE. For
             * example, it is likely that the user *does* want "local"
             * or "localdomain" as a search domain.
             */
            if (domain_is_valid(domain, TRUE, FALSE)) {
                /* pass */
            } else if (domain_is_valid(hostname, TRUE, FALSE)) {
                domain = hostname;
            }

            if (!nm_hostname_is_valid(domain, FALSE))
                domain = NULL;
        }
    }

    if (!nm_strdup_reset(&priv->hostdomain, domain))
        return;

    _LOGT("set host domain to %s%s%s", NM_PRINT_FMT_QUOTE_STRING(priv->hostdomain));

    if (skip_update)
        return;

    if (!priv->updates_queue) {
        gs_free_error GError *error = NULL;

        if (!update_dns(self, FALSE, FALSE, &error))
            _LOGW("could not commit DNS changes: %s", error->message);
    }
}
```